# Scapy change packet length

Tags: python, scapy, packet, icmp

I try change ICMP packet length on 1 byte from Scapy.
But I still see 100 bytes sent in the traffic.
Yes, I want send 100 bytes and see packet length 1 byte in traffic dump.
What options need use? or it is impossible?

```
>>> data = 'A'*100
>>> packet = IP(dst='1.1.1.1')/ICMP(length=1)/Raw(load=data)
>>> send(packet)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXFUV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no length field in ICMP header.  There is one in IP header.

So you can try something like that:

```py
data = 'A' * 100
packet = IP(dst='1.1.1.1', len=29)/ICMP()/Raw(load=data)
send(packet)
```

Here I put 29 as length since my IP header is 20 bytes long and my
ICMP header is 8 byte long.  So this leaves 1 byte for the payload.

You will see in wireshark that 100 `A` characters are actually sent
while the data length displayed by wireshark is 1.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Yes it is work, still need edit field checksum in IP header and ICMP. Then packet will be correct.